# Parse WordNet database into SQL?

Tags: parsing, nlp, wordnet

I would like to have the [WordNet database](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/) in SQL format so I'm thinking about trying to write a [parser for the WordNet files](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/wordnet/man/wndb.5WN.html). However, before I get started I was wondering if there are any existing parsers or if someone has already created a SQL version of the database?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following parsers.

Perl: [Wordnet::QueryData](http://search.cpan.org/~jrennie/WordNet-QueryData-1.49/QueryData.pm)

Python [NLTK] : http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/book/ch02.html#ex-car1

```
>>> from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
>>> wn.synsets('motorcar')
[Synset('car.n.01')]
```

Comment: +1. There are also various Java APIs for handling WordNet and it comes with a (primitive) C API, so no-one should need to write their own parser for this format.

Answer (score 3):

check out http://wnsqlbuilder.sourceforge.net/ (from Related Projects on the WordNet site)